# Crash on open of Android App with AdMob

Tags: android, crash, libgdx, admob

I have developed an Android app with libGDX and have added Admob to it, but when I open the APK on an Android it crashes, stating that the process has stopped.

Here is my code in the Android project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication{

protected AdView adview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = true;


    final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();


    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(graphics.getView(), createLayoutParams());
    View gameview = initializeForView(new BalloonBreakout(), false);


    adview = new AdView(this);
    adview.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adview.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6258330641042393/6188790266");

    adview.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(deviceid).build());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 14);
    adparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(gameview);
    layout.addView(adview, adparams);
    setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's crashing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I've got the error log here, but I don't know why I'm getting a null pointer.

```
E( 3875) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  (AndroidRuntime)
E( 3875)    at com.sevenbit.Balloon_Breakout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)(AndroidRuntime)
```

Line 37 is:

```
setContentView(graphics.getView(), createLayoutParams());
```

However when I deleted this line, I still got a null pointer at the same place, line 37.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack trace, including the "Caused by:" part. It is important. Also, you can just copy/paste it here instead of taking a photo of your screen. Just use 4 spaces before each line to make a code block.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (like all the other libgdx posts I have seen lately) is that libgdx AndroidApplication#initializeForView call Activity#setContextView to set its own layout (which it shouldn't). You then call setContextView with your own layout.

It crashes presumably because some libgdx code is assuming that it's layout object has been loaded but it's not there because you have replaced it with your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. Any idea as how to fix it?

Comment: Try to find some libgdx method that sets up the libgdx stuff but doesn't call setContentView under the covers (that is very bad form, it really shouldn't be doing that without making it explicitly clear).

Comment: I have no idea where that stuff goes on, any chance you do?

Comment: I don't code using libgdx. Suggest you start here http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should post or look at your stack trace. That will tell you what line your code is failing at. Otherwise people will have to guess from looking at your code. The problem may be anywhere.

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment. It's more along the lines of a comment than an answer

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for a comment. Just trying to help.